# Не видит путь к ресурсам, в следствии чего эксепшен

Tags: java, swing, файловая-система, path, resources

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Только начал писать проект но тут по факту всего 2.5 класса поэтому для общего понимания происходящего должно хватить.

Comment: может надо добавить / перед img? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Попробуйте после getClass() прописать еще и getClassLoader() и только потом получить getResource()

Comment: Попоробовал добать / перед img и второй совет тоже учел. Ситуация к сожалению не изменилась. Суть в том что это проект по факту автора с курса и делал в точку в точку но к сожалению когда тот нажал на "mark as Resourses Boot" у него папка с картинками стала отображаться как пакет, а у меня продолжает отображатся как директория.